# Change folder name from YYYYMMM to MMMM YYYY

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename

I need a batch that can rename folder name from YYYYMMM to MMMM YYYY

Example:

```
2019JAN to January 2019
2019FEB to February 2019
etc...
```

My batch below only managed to rename from `YYYYMMM`  to `MMMYYYY` only. Appreciate if someone can help to expand my code and achieve desired output. Thank you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  echo ren !folder! "!folder:~-3!!folder:~0,4!"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder rename task can be done with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "JAN=January"
set "FEB=February"
set "MAR=March"
set "APR=April"
set "MAY=May"
set "JUN=June"
set "JUL=July"
set "AUG=August"
set "SEP=September"
set "OCT=October"
set "NOV=November"
set "DEC=December"
for /D %%I in (20*) do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    call ren "%%I" "%%!FolderName:~4!%% !FolderName:~0,4!"
)
endlocal
```

But a folder name in the format `yyyy-MM` would be better because the folders with that name listed ordered by name are listed also in correct chronological order.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "JAN=01"
set "FEB=02"
set "MAR=03"
set "APR=04"
set "MAY=05"
set "JUN=06"
set "JUL=07"
set "AUG=08"
set "SEP=09"
set "OCT=10"
set "NOV=11"
set "DEC=12"
for /D %%I in (20*) do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    call ren "%%I" "!FolderName:~0,4!-%%!FolderName:~4!%%"
)
endlocal
```

For a **recursive** renaming of all subfolders in folder of the batch file with a four digit year and a three characters abbreviated month in folder name the **FOR** loop should be modified to:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp020*" /AD /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\\20[0123456789][0123456789][ADFJMNOS][ACEOPU][BCGLNPRTVY]$"') do (
    set "FolderName=%%~nxI"
    call ren "%%I" "%%!FolderName:~4!%% !FolderName:~0,4!"
)
```

The regular expression is not perfect to avoid false positive matches, i.e. matched could be also folders starting with `20[0-9][0-9]`, but the next three characters are not exactly one of the twelve month abbreviations. But this should not be a problem in this case.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`